# karma start is failing

Tags: typescript, karma-runner

I have installed `karma` with `npm install karma` and installed `karma typings` with all other dependencies. But to my surprise it posted errors when I run `karma start`.

```
ERROR [plugin]: Error during loading"/node_modules/karma-typescript" plugin: Cannot find module 'browser-resolve'
```

Do I miss anything?

My dependencies are as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
"@types/karma": "^0.13.33",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"enzyme": "^2.5.1",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-typescript": "^2.1.2",
"karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.2",
"source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
"ts-loader": "^0.9.4",
"tslint-eslint-rules": "^2.1.0",
"typescript": "^2.0.8",
"webpack": "^1.13.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmnn interesting, i've seen such a problem before and this is how i got it solve. "install browser-resolve" with

```
npm install browser-resolve
```

and incase you encounter module / dependency related errors, use this tool system-wide to install missing dependencies for all your node projects

```
npm install -g npm-install-missing
```

or with specific project directory use

```
npm-install-missing
```

Comment: i have the same issue. why is this needed. I think npm will install depending packages for me?